# How to find PowerShell Static Classes and Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I find what Static Classes and Methods there is available in PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: You mean commands you can execute? See Get-Command http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176842.aspx Or do you mean static .Net classes and it's static methods? These are not Powershell specific.

Comment: Yes, I meant .Net classes and static methods that you can use with PowerShell. I don't know .Net, so it would be nice to see a list of available classes and methods one can use via PowerShell.

Comment: You can use all .Net classes and they don't even need to be static either. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347574.aspx I think you are better off browsing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any .NET types and their static methods from PowerShell. To enumerate all that are currently loaded into your AppDomain, you can do:

```
 [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | foreach { $_.GetTypes() } | foreach { $_.GetMethods() } | where { $_.IsStatic } | select DeclaringType, Name | format-table
```

Remember, you are not limited to static methods, you can also instantiate the types using `new-object` and call instance methods. You can use `get-member` on an instance to get the methods on a type.

Also, if you want to list your available CmdLets, just invoke:

```
Get-Command
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Is there a way to remove duplicates from this list?

Comment: I don't think it has duplicates, but perhaps subclasses report the same static method twice (Do you have an example of a duplicate ?)

Comment: When I run this on my PowerShell console, I get eg.                               
System.Convert                            ToDateTime                              
System.Convert                            ToDateTime                              
System.Convert                            ToString                                
System.Convert                            ToString

Comment: Ah, that's different overloads of the methods. You can either filter by name (if you don't care about the overloads), or you could include parameter information in the list - depends on what you need it for.

Answer (score 4):

To get the static members of a type or object, pipe it to Get-Member and specify the Static switch:

```
[math] | Get-Member -Static
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr driis, you are the man !!! Totally made my day !

I just took the liberty to modify it a little bit so it returns the whole list without duplicates:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | foreach { $_.GetTypes() } | foreach { $_.GetMethods() } | where { $_.IsStatic } | select DeclaringType | Out-File assemblies.txt
```

and then read the assemblies.txt file but only get unique rows :

```
cat .\assemblies.txt Get-Unique
```

Comment: Thanks i also could create unique file
cat .\assemblies.txt Get-Unique | Out-File unique.txt

Answer (score 0):

You have the classes ( static or otherwise ) from .NET framework.

Once you have the class, you can use `Get-Member`:

```
[Environment] | Get-Member
```

PS: "Windows PowerShell Cookbook" by Lee Holmes has an Appendix which lists some useful classes, from Powershell / SysAdmin point of view. That list( and the book) is very useful.